# get list of checked checkboxes through arraycontroller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, boolean, iteration, nsarraycontroller

i have an arraycontroller bound to the tableview. i need to return the number of checked checkoxes in the table. the arraycontroller is filled with nsmutabledictionaries. this is the code i have so far:

```
-(IBAction)getlist:(id)sender{
checkedchecks = 0;
for (NSManagedObject *a in imagescontroller.arrangedObjects)
{

 ////MISSING CODE GOES HERE
}
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init] ;
[alert setMessageText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)checkedchecks ]];
[alert runModal];

}
```

now i would need to know how i can count all the values that are boolean and are set to yes.. thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I think you do not have to loop through your objects.

```
NSUInteger checked = [(NSNumber*)[imagesController.arrangedObjects
                valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.boolProperty"] integerValue];
```

This is sort of a hack because a `BOOL` will be interpreted as 0 or 1.
The semantically more correct way is.

```
NSUInteger checked = [imagesController.arrangedObjects
                 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                   @"boolProperty == %@", @YES]].count;
```

This is assuming that you have an array (`arrangedObjects`) which contains instances of `NSManagedObject` (or subclass thereof). The objects have a property called `boolProperty` of type `NSNumber` (which is the standard wrapper for BOOL values in managed objects). When a row is displayed, it is marked as checked if this `boolProperty` is `@YES`. If you change the checkmark (e.g. by selecting the row), the model should be updated: the appropriate managed object should be retrieved and the `boolProperty` toggled.

Comment: thanks! but doesnt seem to work, Always get 0! i also get a warning: Implicit conversion loses integer precision. NSUinteger to int

Comment: and on your first one i get the message: Property "intValue" not found on object of type "id"

Comment: See my corrections. These were minor issues. If you are getting zero, you did not save the checked bools properly.

Comment: Hello! still getting 0. what do you mean by "save the chcked bools property"? i used this code to add the data to the array controller: `[imgdtl setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[a valueForKey:@"agency"]]];`

Comment: sorry but even after googling around i still dont understand your checked bools part.. could you please explain? thanks

Comment: is this the part you mean? `[imgdtl setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] ...` if so they aready are at yes and its still returning 0

Comment: No. The filtered array should contain objects if the correct property is addressed and there are true bools. According to the above, your entity instance is called `imgdt` (why?) and your `boolProperty` is called `object` (why?).

Comment: imgdtl is my image mutable dictionary. i add the values to the dictionary and at the end i use `[imagescontroller addObject:imgdtl];` to add my mutable dictionary to the arraycontroller. at least this is how i was told to do on another question in the past